# Broken libc6 makes system unbootable when I install packages via apt-get

Tags: debian, apt

I tried to install Skype on my amd64 Debian 7, after believing the page that told me to upgrade libc6 and allow the x86 architecture. When I started downloading such packages and upgrading libc6 my system broke and at boot I kept getting this message:
`Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-close.c: 743: _dl_close: Assertion map >l_init_called' failed!`
(Which happens to be the same one when I type `/lib/libc.so.6` on the terminal)

I used a rescue disk, erased all the x86 packages and deleted the x86 architecture but if I install something from apt-get, the system breaks again and the OS wont boot until the `ld.so.cache` file is deleted.

If  `ldd --version` is run on the terminal the output is: `ldd (Debian EGLIBC 2.13-38+deb7u6) 2.13`

What should I do in order to be able to install packages again via apt-get without having to rescue the system each time afterwards?

Comment: My advice would be to do a total reinstll as you broke part of your toolchain

Comment: Can't I just reinstall what I need?

Answer (score 0):

On Debian 7 amd64 [Wheezy] I manually installed TFTP using `dpkg`. By mistake I installed `libc6-udep` version 2.19 besides having `libc6 2.13` [stable for wheezy] installed.

After that I encountered same problems; `apt-get` broke system with exact same message.

With the Synaptic package mgr I removed `libc6-udep 2.19` which solved the error for me.